# How to get updated props in setInterval by using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, react-hooks

I want to execute `setInterval` when user click a button, all of the logic is fine to me except for calling `clearInterval`.

When `props.time === 0`, I want to execute `clearInterval`. However, I found that I can't get updated `props.time`. It always equal to the initial value in the `setInterval` callback.

I am newbie in react and react-hook. I find several hook such as `useEffect`、 `useRef` that may help me solve the problem. However, I can't understand how to use it. I hope someone can give me some tips.

Thanks

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(undefined)

const countDown = () => {
  const timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (props.time === 0) clearInterval(timer)

    // execute the logic of "props.time = props.time - 1"
  }, 1000) 
  setTimer(timerInterval)
}

return (
  <button onClick={countDown} />
)
```

Comment: `props.time` will never change if the parent won't pass a new prop value. beside, `setInterval` returns the interval `id` and not the current time. please share more relevant code

Comment: I am sure that `props.time` changes per second. I thought the key point is it can't get the updated `props` from parent component in `setInterval` callback.

Comment: read through [this article](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) which explains the problem and the solution.

Comment: @Yaelet Yeah, I have read this article. However, when I try to use `useInterval` to replace `setInterval`. It throws error `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`. I don't know how to use react-hooks properly. Now, I am stuck at here...

Comment: Can you creat a sandbox example with your problem? It's hard to tell from your current code how you implemented `useInterval` and why you're getting the error. Also, try to Google the error, react has a few answers as to why you may see that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you're looking for.

A `useRef` is the right place to keep the `setInterval` reference. It will be the same reference on every render. It will not change.

**From React DOCS:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

> **useRef**
>
> However, useRef() is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.
>
> This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object yourself is that useRef will give you the same ref object on every render.
>
> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.

```js
function App() {

  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  const timerRef = React.useRef(null);

  if (time === 0) {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }
  
  function countDown(startFrom) {
    setTime(startFrom);
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prevState) => prevState -1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Time: {time}</div>
      <button onClick={()=>countDown(3)}>Countdown from 3</button>
      <button onClick={()=>countDown(5)}>Countdown from 5</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I am looking for. Previous, I put `if (time === 0) { clearInterval(timerRef.current); }` inside of `setInterval`, so I can't get updated value of `time`. Now, I know I should put `if (time === 0) { ... }` outside of `setInterval` and execute `clearInterval` when `time` decrease to 0. Thank you a lot.